# How can I get the result when I use new version of tkz-euclide?

Tags: tkz-euclide

This is mycode

```
    \documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide} % loads TikZ
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{2}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
    \tkzDefPoint(-\a,0){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(\a,0){B}
    %\tkzDefCircle[through](O,C)
    \tkzDrawCircle(O,A)
    \tkzGetLength{rO}
\tkzDefPointOnCircle[angle=130,center=O,radius=\rO pt]
\tkzGetPoint{C}
\tkzDefPointOnCircle[angle=80,center=O,radius=\rO pt]
\tkzGetPoint{D}
\tkzDefPointOnCircle[angle=40,center=O,radius=\rO pt]
\tkzGetPoint{E}
    \tkzDefPointBy[symmetry=center C](A) \tkzGetPoint{M}
    \tkzDefPointBy[symmetry=center D](A) \tkzGetPoint{N}
    \tkzDefPointBy[symmetry=center E](A) \tkzGetPoint{P}
    \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,M,O,N,P,C,D,E)
    \tkzDrawSegments(A,M A,N A,P A,B)
    \tkzMarkSegments[mark=|](A,C M,C)
    \tkzMarkSegments[mark=||](A,D D,N)
    \tkzMarkSegments[mark=|||](A,E E,P)
    \foreach \p/\g in {A/180,B/0,M/90,O/-90,N/90,P/90,C/120,D/90,E/90}
    \path (\p)+(\g:3mm) node{$\p$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I got

[image]

How can I get correct result?

Comment: I'm sorry to have changed the syntax several times but I didn't imagine the introduction of `lua` when I started to write this package. From now on the syntax will not move and the next calculation engine with lua will be transparent to the users.

Comment: @AlainMatthes Thank you very much for new version. I have to change syntax about 20 pictures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the last version tkz-euclide 5.02c

```
\tkzGetLength{rO} is wrong
```

> p.17
> 0.3. Changes with previous versions `\tkzCalcLength` `\tkzGetLength` gives result in cm;

Remark: you define the macro \a, \rOA is not useful

```
`\tkzDefPointOnCircle[angle=130,center=O,radius=\rOA pt]` replaced by `\tkzDefPointOnCircle[R= center O angle 130 radius \rOA]`
```

**the code**

```
    \documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide} % loads TikZ
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{2}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
    \tkzDefPoint(-\a,0){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(\a,0){B}
    %\tkzDefCircle[through](O,C)
    \tkzDrawCircle(O,A)
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %\tkzGetLength{rO}<--- wrong
    %
    % \tkzCalcLength(O,A)\tkzGetLength{rOA}%<-- not useful
    %
%\tkzDefPointOnCircle[angle=130,center=O,radius=\rOA pt]
\tkzDefPointOnCircle[R= center O angle 130 radius \a]
%
\tkzGetPoint{C}
%\tkzDefPointOnCircle[angle=80,center=O,radius=\rO pt]
\tkzDefPointOnCircle[R= center O angle 60 radius \a]
\tkzGetPoint{D}
%\tkzDefPointOnCircle[angle=40,center=O,radius=\rO pt]
\tkzDefPointOnCircle[R= center O angle 40 radius \a]
%
\tkzGetPoint{E}
    \tkzDefPointBy[symmetry=center C](A) \tkzGetPoint{M}
    \tkzDefPointBy[symmetry=center D](A) \tkzGetPoint{N}
    \tkzDefPointBy[symmetry=center E](A) \tkzGetPoint{P}
    \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,M,O,N,P,C,D,E)
    \tkzDrawSegments(A,M A,N A,P A,B)
    \tkzMarkSegments[mark=|](A,C M,C)
    \tkzMarkSegments[mark=||](A,D D,N)
    \tkzMarkSegments[mark=|||](A,E E,P)
    \foreach \p/\g in {A/180,B/0,M/90,O/-90,N/90,P/90,C/120,D/90,E/90}
    \path (\p)+(\g:3mm) node{$\p$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I couldn't have said it better. Have you tried compiling with the `lua` option and lualatex?

Comment: @Alain Matthes with the option lua and a complation with lualatex, we obtain with the John Paul Peter's code : Undefined control sequence.
\tkzGetLength ...e #1\endcsname {\tkzLengthResult
                                                  }
l.11     \tkzGetLength{rO}

Comment: @Alain Matthes I don't know the old version, could this code work?

Comment: Yes it's normal, with lua you have to use your code. The syntax remains the same ! Simply the compilation time is shorter and the precision is better. However, all this is not visible on a small program.